# Unable to view video files using Google Doc Viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-document-viewer

I am trying to view video files (formats like .WebM, .MPEG4, .3GPP, .MOV, .AVI, .MPEGPS, .WMV, .FLV) using Google Doc Viewer but unable to view it and getting error **No Preview Available**. My code is as follows :

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=MySiteUrl/sample.flv&embedded=true" style="margin:0 auto; width:800px; height:800px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I am facing same problem with other formats like (.AI,.PSD,.TTF,.XPS,.ZIP and .RAR).

Is there any problem with code ?
Did google doc viewer really support video files ?
Google Doc Viewer and Google Drive API are same or different ? 
Can anyone please suggest any other DOC viewer which supports Images, Video and above mention formats ?

Comment: where did you get the https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=MySiteUrl/sample.flv&embedded=true URI format?  Try https://drive.google.com/file/d/VIDEO_FILE_ID/view

Comment: Take a look at the new google sites.  It's easy to embed videos there and you can view them on the web easily.  No addon required.

Comment: Did you get any solution on this? Please help me out.

Comment: @Yuyutsu sorry body unfortunately not.